# Why can I call instance method in instance init block?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

The instance initialisation block is invoked before constructor but **this** is available in it already. And so we can call any public or private methods. But why? Only the constructor guarantees the instance creation and availability of **this**

```
public class Test {

    {
        this.privatePrint();
        this.publicPrint();
    }

    public Test() {
        System.out.print(" Constructor ");
    }

    public void publicPrint() {
        System.out.print(" public ");
    }

    public void privatePrint() {
        System.out.print(" private ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

The output is `private  public  Constructor`

I tested it on jdk 11 and 17

I was surprised by the behavior of the order of object initialization methods

Comment: "Only the constructor guarantees the instance creation and availability of this" - could you clarify what you mean by that, and how you've come to that conclusion?

Comment: Just because an initialization block is executed before the constructor does not mean that at that moment the object doesn't already exist.

If a initialization block would not know what object it belongs to (and therefor allow the use of `this`), what would be the point of initialization blocks? If initialization blocks wouldn't have access to the object they belong to they could literally do no initializing of said object and that would make initialization blocks a pretty useless feature.

Comment: Checkout the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) for details.

Comment: Remember that a constructor has already been called: `public class Test extends Object`.  All Java classes extend `Object` and its constructors are called first.  Then your class's constructors get called, including the init block.  Well that's the theory, I suspect really that `Object`s are created just by allocating heap memory for efficiency, so really `this` just points to the heap memory that's been created for your object.

Comment: @markspace - the heap node's header will also be initialized ... including the information that says what the instance's class will be.  Bui, most likely the call to the `Object()` constructor will be optimized away (by the JIT compiler or the runtime system) because it does nothing.   (It would be interesting to see what would happen if you modded the JVM codebase and put some code into the `Object()` constructor ...)

Comment: It is not executed befor the constructor. It is executed after the explicit or implicit `super()’ call *in* the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I see that `this` becomes available immediately after `super()` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Language Specification ([12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) has the exact details.

Basically the Java Compiler creates for your class the same bytecode as the following class (where the call to the super constructor and the instance initializers explicitly written):

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        super();  // Point 3: call the super constructor
        {  // Point 4: execute instance initializers and instance variable initializers
            this.privatePrint();
            this.publicPrint();
        }
        // Point 5: Execute the rest of the body of this constructor
        System.out.print(" Constructor ");
    }

    public void publicPrint() {
        System.out.print(" public ");
    }

    public void privatePrint() {
        System.out.print(" private ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```